# Keycloak Springboot multiple clients

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I am using Keycloak with Standard flow(Authorization code grant) to protect my REST endpoints. I am using keycloak starter dependency in my springboot project.

I have the necessary configuration in application.properties file.

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=https://...../auth
keycloak.realm=...
keycloak.resource=client1
keycloak.credentials.secret=...
keycloak.public-client=true
```

The setup is working fine. Whenever any REST endpoints are accessed, user is redirected to keycloak login page. After successfull authentication a code is returned, which is exchanged for access token and this token is passed, which is then verified against the right roles(I have the security config setup in my application with appropriate antmatchers to handle this).

The issue I have now is, if I create a new client in Keycloak, say client2, I want my application to work for both client1 and client2, how can I achieve this? Is it possible to make this dynamic(I need not restart the server)

Is there a standard way to handle multiple clients in this kinda setup?

Comment: Hi @pvpkiran i spend a lot of time to understand how can i implement keycloack with angular, can you please explain me how keycloack / spring boot valide access token and when token is store and how can i refresh access token thanks :)

Comment: @pvpkiran: I am also figuring out the same thing. Do you have any solution for this yet?

Comment: @vijay no there is nothing that comes out of the box from keycloak. I raised a feature request to keycloak. No updates on that yet.

Comment: @pvpkiran: That's sad. So have you found any work around for this or have you dropped it?

Comment: One work around is to remove all keycloak dependencies from Ur project and have a http filter to intercept all requests and get token from request  header in this filter  and make a call to introspect endpoint of keycloak and check validity of the token ( check token validity and client info) .. again this has limitations. U cannot use introspect API with public access type clients

Comment: @pvpkiran: Thanks for the reply. I tried to get the access token but I am getting only ID token. Do you know how can I get the access token from the filter ? I am using spring cloud gateway.

Comment: @Vijay i don't know spring security provide this feature or not, but i save tokens in db (UUID,JWTtoken) when user login in system and in Filter i check header and cookie for support with api and front (cookie), if this exists in db so jwt token will put in request header ...

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be resolved by overriding the `KeycloakAuthenticationProvider` class.

```
public class CustomKeycloakAuthenticationProvider extends KeycloakAuthenticationProvider {

private GrantedAuthoritiesMapper grantedAuthoritiesMapper;

public void setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(GrantedAuthoritiesMapper grantedAuthoritiesMapper) {
    this.grantedAuthoritiesMapper = grantedAuthoritiesMapper;
}

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    KeycloakAuthenticationToken token = (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) authentication;
    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

    for (String role : token.getAccount().getRoles()) {
        grantedAuthorities.add(new KeycloakRole(role));
    }
    //Setting all roles from all clients
    for (Map.Entry<String, AccessToken.Access> accessEntry : token.getAccount().getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken().getResourceAccess().entrySet()) {
        for (String role : accessEntry.getValue().getRoles()) {
            grantedAuthorities.add(new KeycloakRole(role));
        }
    }
    return new KeycloakAuthenticationToken(token.getAccount(), token.isInteractive(), mapAuthorities(grantedAuthorities));
}

private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapAuthorities(
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    return grantedAuthoritiesMapper != null
            ? grantedAuthoritiesMapper.mapAuthorities(authorities)
            : authorities;
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
    return KeycloakAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass);
}
```

}

This will set all the assigned roles to the Spring's authentication object.
Note that you need to configure this in the SecurityConfig class as well.

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    CustomKeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = customKeycloakAuthenticationProvider();
    keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
    auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
}

@Bean
public CustomKeycloakAuthenticationProvider customKeycloakAuthenticationProvider() {
    return new CustomKeycloakAuthenticationProvider();
}
```

Also remove the property `keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings` (this is set to false by default i.e. to just use realm role mappings).